# Conditional classname and text (Rails)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, controller

I'm pretty new to Rails and trying some basic stuff like conditional classes.

On the 'show' view I have an element that changes styling depending on the stock availability, but also the text changes accordingly.

People keep saying the controller should be as small as possible, but placing this conditional in the view also feels dirty. Is this really the best way?

Current controller:

```
def show
  @tyre = Tyres::Tyre.find_by_id(params[:id])

  if @tyre.in_stock
    @availability = I18n.t("products.filter.other.in_stock")
    @availability_class = 'i-check-circle color--success'
  else
    @availability = I18n.t("products.filter.other.not_in_stock")
    @availability_class = 'i-cross-circle color--important'
  end
end
```

---

**Edit:**

Controller:

```
def show
  @tyre = Tyres::Tyre.find_by_id(params[:id])

  if @tyre.in_stock
    @availability_append = ".in_stock"
  else
    @availability_append = ".not_in_stock"
  end

  @availability = I18n.t("products.filter.other#{@availability_append}")
end
```

View:

```
.xs-12.description__status
  %i{class: (@tyre.in_stock? ? 'i-check-circle color--success' : 'i-cross-circle color--important')}
  = @availability
```

Comment: You can put your `view` related code snippets to the helpers, in your case `tyre_helper.rb` is the file.

Comment: Alright, I changed it. See my edit above :)

Comment: Do you want any more change now or are you still seeking some solution?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I forgot to add more info.

You suggested to use a helper but a colleague suggested just putting the class partial in the view and keeping the text in the controller. I tried his solution (see above) and this already seems much cleaner.

I also want to try putting it in the helper as you suggested, but I have no idea where to start... I still have a feeling this could be done better, that's why I added my edited code :) Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clean your **controller** `tyres_controller.rb` (i suppose) method,

```
def show
 @tyre = Tyre.find(params[:id]) # I believe you have a model named 'tyre'
end
```

Then, there will be a file named `tyres_helper.rb` in your `myproject/app/helpers/`. Put the following code there,

```
def tyre_availability(tyre)  # it'll return an array with two values, first one is class name, second one is localized value
  if tyre.in_stock
    return 'i-check-circle color--success', I18n.t("products.filter.other.in_stock")
  else 
    return 'i-cross-circle color--important', I18n.t("products.filter.other.not_in_stock")
  end
end
```

and, in the **view** you can use,

```
.xs-12.description__status
  %i{:class => tyre_availability(@tyre)[0]}
  = tyre_availability(@tyre)[1]
```

Comment: Thank you! That looks a lot like what I just made:

Controller:

def show
    @tyre = Tyres::Tyre.find(params[:id])
end

Helper:

  def tyre_stock(tyre)
    tyre.in_stock? ? 'i-check-circle color--success' : 'i-cross-circle color--important'
  end

  def tyre_stock_text(tyre)
    stock_status = tyre.in_stock? ? "in_stock" : "not_in_stock"
    I18n.t("products.filter.other.#{stock_status}")
  end

View:

              %i{class: tyre_stock(@tyre)}
              = tyre_stock_text(@tyre)

Comment: Annoying you can't use multi-line code in comments. Anyway, thank you! Your solution is perfect